# CSS selector for nested elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to stagger the fade-in animations of images in a gallery. I've boiled down my problem to the attached snippet.
Not sure whether the snippets here allow for SCSS but in any case, I think my mistake is in the CSS selector where I set the animation-delay.

```css
@keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.masonry {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  animation: FadeIn 0.5s linear;
}

@for $i from 1 through 20 {
  .item > .cld-image > img:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: 1000ms * $i;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="cld-image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="cld-image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="cld-image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think my mistake is in the CSS selector where I set the animation-delay.

Your thoughts are correct! The selector where you add the `animation-delay` is incorrect, since there's no `animation` added to the actual `<img>` tags(logically).

To fix this, you have to either add the `animation-delay` to the `.item` class, or add the `animation` itself to the `<img>` tags.

Comment: Thanks! Adding the animation-delay to the item worked. Adding the animation to the image didn't, but I might have missed something. In any case, thanks.